# Chaining promises in nodejs with request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, request-promise

I know there is a lot of stuff out there explaing the concepts but I am still confused why my node.js example does not work.

I have a main function

```
function main(){
login()
    .then(
        function(result) {
            return getMyInfo();
        }
    );
```

and two API calls (getMyInfo and login) like this:

```
function login(){
    const options = {
        ...
        },
    };
    return rp(options);
}
```

Now I want to call my main function from another file

```
main()
    .then(
        function(thisIsWhatINeed) {
            console.log(thisIsWhatINeed);
        }
    );
```

Somehow this still returns undefined for me, can you help you finding out why?
In my opinion both login() and getMyInfo() return a promise and therefore main() also returns a promise because it return getMyInfo..

Comment: `main` doesn't return anything...

Comment: why not using async/await and native promises ? Makes using promises easier.

Comment: I didn't know about await, seems like something that is worth checking out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the promise from your `main` function:

```
function main() {
   return login().then(function(result) {
       return getMyInfo();
   });
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks this worked. I thought if i have 
return getMyInfo()
in the main(), then this will be the return value of main()